# Knowing when bash is done running a command through a FIFO pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, fifo

I'm trying to link a web-based terminal with bash**.**

My current attempt to do so is spawning a shell pointing a FIFO pipe to its input, like this:

*Terminal 1*

```
$ mkfifo pipe
$ bash <> pipe
file1    file2    file4
```

*Terminal 2*

```
$ echo "ls" > pipe
```

As you might be able to tell, I am only getting command responses from spawning the shell in *Terminal 1* (obviously). Is it possible for me to tell if bash is idle or not? I need to know when to show `$PS1` on the client side.

If I run something like `apt-get install curl -y`, the command is continuous and finishes when it finishes. I need to know when it is finished so that on the front-end, I can show the terminal prompt.

Any ideas?